# Script to send mail if there has been no entry in a log file for a certain amount of time

Tags: shell-script, logs, email, monitoring, notifications

How would I write a script which can send an alert mail if there is no entry in the log file for more than 3 hours.

Comment: You should probably look at [monitoring software](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17473/linux-server-monitoring-software)

Answer (score 2):

A bit convoluted, but it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=`date +%s`
max_age=10800 # 3 hours in seconds

if [ $(($now - `stat -c '%Y' $1`)) -gt $max_age ]; then
    echo "file hasn't been updated in $max_age seconds"
fi
```

Call the script with the filename as the only argument.

Comment: I might be missing something, but where is this sending an email?

Comment: If you run this as a cron job, you'll get email whenever it generates output.  Alternatively, run it by hand and add something like `| mail -s 'Oh no!' you@your.domain` to the `echo` line.

Comment: Hi Max,
 Thanks for your help....But still i'm not able to execute the script successfully...The error which i'm getting is 

printf: `(': invalid format character

Comment: @Flup, ahh right. My bad.

Comment: @Abdul Make sure that you have the quotes exactly as they are above.  Also make sure you are running the script with `bash`.

Comment: @Max, ya i'm running the script with bash & the codes are exactly same what you have given..But still i get the same error...Could you help me to figure out what the mistake is????

Comment: My apologies, it appears I might be running a more recent version of `bash`.  I've made a small change above (the `now=` line) -- please try that.

Comment: @Max,ya its working fine now :)Thanks a lot :)